# Trying to fetch multiple ids from postgres table which column is type jsonB

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to fetch multiple ids from postgres. So here my requirements is I have multiple ids so all that ids which are stored in ruleset tables at rules column which is jsonb type. So while I'm trying to fetch those ids from ruleset table I'm not able to fetch so the query what I run is :

```
SELECT * FROM rulesets
Where rules IN('2c084b4e-9658-4f50-afe4-a0a820d1d51d', '23de26ef-c3aa-4f31-81dd-1b63e1e2f699',
                   '7a1af945-c5bd-4709-b5f3-24180398da7d', '665ecd7e-900a-4b30-b6da-19ff7a0068b3')
```

So here while running this query I'm facing this error :

```
ERROR: Token "2c084b4e" is invalid.invalid input syntax for type json ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json SQL state: 22P02 Detail: Token "2c084b4e" is invalid. Character: 40 Context: JSON data, line 1: 2c084b4e...
```

And here because it's jsonB Type I have type casted with text but the result is coming Empty. So here please help me to give the right query to fetch the multiple rules from the ruleset table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT * FROM rulesets
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(rulesets.rules) AS elem
    WHERE elem.value IN ('2c084b4e-9658-4f50-afe4-a0a820d1d51d', 
        '23de26ef-c3aa-4f31-81dd-1b63e1e2f699',
        '7a1af945-c5bd-4709-b5f3-24180398da7d', 
        '665ecd7e-900a-4b30-b6da-19ff7a0068b3')
);
```

Comment: HI @puttsche the above query i have to add that in this operator list.Here is the list                                                   OPERATORS = {
    'is_null': lambda f, a: f.is_(None) if a else f.isnot(None),
    'eq': lambda f, a: f == a,
    'ne': lambda f, a: f != a,
    'gt': lambda f, a: f > a,
    'lt': lambda f, a: f < a,
    'gte': lambda f, a: f >= a,
    'lte': lambda f, a: f <= a,
    'like': lambda f, a: f.like(a),
    'ilike': lambda f, a: f.ilike(a)
}